# Proguard and Scala default arguments

Tags: android, scala, proguard

I have an Android Scala app that uses SBT + ProGuard for building.

In a library project I have this:

```
package es.fcc.bibl.bd.sincr

class Columna[T] { ... }

class TablaBase {
     lazy val columnas: List[Columna[_]] = ....
}

trait Soporte {
    this: TablaBase =>

    def fabricaSoporte(w: Writer, cols: List[Columna[_]] = columnas) {
}
```

in my app code, I have this:

```
package es.fcc.incidencias.bd

object sgiein extends TablaBase with Soporte { .... }
```

and when building my project, I get these cryptic errors:

```
Warning: es.fcc.incidencias.bd.sgiein: can't find referenced method 'void es$fcc$bibl$bd$sincr$TablaBaseSincronizada$_setter_$cols_$eq(scala.collection.immutable.List)' in program class es.fcc.incidencias.bd.sgiein$
Warning: es.fcc.incidencias.bd.sgiein: can't find referenced method 'scala.collection.immutable.List cols()' in program class es.fcc.incidencias.bd.sgiein$

     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     You may need to recompile the code.
(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
```

The problem is related with the default value of the argument `cols`.
If I remove that argument, everything builds ok.

I've tried to change the ProGuard options to these with no luck:

```
-keepclassmembers class es.fcc.bibl.bd.sincr.TablaBaseSincronizada* {
    ** *(**);
}
-keepclassmembers class es.fcc.incidencias.bd.* {
    ** *(**);
}
```

I don't understand why I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that these errors can be safely ignored.

It must be some internal error in `ProGuard`.

Use the `-dontwarn` directive in the `ProGuard` configuration for that purpose.